# How to write rspec test for json response from jquery file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2

I have a form that uses the jquery-file-upload plugin.  It posts to a controller and the return objects are both json types.

Controller

```
def create
  @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])
  if @upload.save
    render :json => [ @upload.to_jq_upload ].to_json
  else
    render :json => [ @upload.to_jq_upload.merge({ :error => "custom_failure" }) ].to_json
  end
end
```

I have the following rspec test:

```
describe "post 'create' " do
  before(:each) do
    @upload = Factory(:upload)
    @attr_upload = {:photo => sample_file}
  end

  describe "success" do
    it "should  create a new upload object" do
      lambda do
        post :create, :upload => @attr_upload, :format => :json
      end.should change(Upload, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

which works. I would like to test both for failure as in a form was posted without a file or the file was too large or of the wrong format.

Here is my test.

```
describe "failure" do
  before(:each) do
    @upload = Factory(:upload)
    @attr_upload = {:photo => sample_file("too_big.jpg")}
  end

  it "should not create a new upload object" do
    lambda do
      post :create, :upload => @attr_upload, :format => :json
    end.should_not change(Upload, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

This does not work. Here is the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"uploads", :id=>#<Upload id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, photo_file_name: "too_big.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 7483326, photo_updated_at: "2011-07-19 02:24:06">}
```

Here is my routes file:

```
Hbg::Application.routes.draw do      
  resources :uploads
end
```

Why am I getting this error when I am submitting the form to the 'create' action? The response is supposed to be a json object.

Comment: I'm a newbie with RoR, but only thing currently I like in Ruby, that other people code starts looking much readable. :D Sorry for offtopic.

Comment: Could you show sample_file method? Error should be somwhere inside it. Your specs look legit.